# Invalid syntax after if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am doing a simple script and is

```
if answer = y
    print ("yay")
if answer = n
    print ("sorry)"
```

when I run it says invalid syntax and I tried doing this instead:

```
if answer = ("y")
    print ("yay")
if answer = ("n")
    print ("sorry")
```

and then it still says invalid syntax and all the space after

```
if answer = ("y")
```

is red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has three errors:

1. Conditionals in Python are followed by colon (`:`).
2. To check the equality between two conditions, you use '==' operator
3. Simply writing y refers to a variable. To check if the answer is equal to the character y, you enclose it with quotes like `'y'`.

The correct syntax would be:

```
if answer == 'y':
    print('yay')

if answer == 'n':
    print('sorry')
```

Comment: there is a fourth: `print ("sorry)"`

Comment: Yeah this works, But maybe use `elif answer == 'n':` would be better?

Comment: Correct, but the question was about syntactical issues.

Answer (score -1):

Reported errors are correct.

Python interpreter expect colon (:) after conditional statements(if, else)

Also "==" operator stands for equality check, not "="

Comment: This simply repeats parts of the already-posted, correct, complete answer. I suggest removing this redundant noise answer unless you can improve it substantially to provide a significant improvement over any existing answer. (For limited improvements, post a comment or propose an edit.)